# Server returns 415 HTTP code for no obvious reason

Tags: java, android, spring, http-error

I'm sending an object using Spring for Android RestTemplate class. It sends valid JSON (I've checked every-which-way), the http headers and content type are correct.

Sending the object:

```
try {
            Event event = new Event();
            // Set event parameters.
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String url = Const.ADD_EVENT_REQUEST + Const.getRequiredRequestParameters(app);
            return restTemplate.postForObject(url, event, Boolean.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Add event task", e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
```

Receiving the object on the server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Boolean createEvent(@RequestBody Event event) {
        try {
            Logger.getLogger(EventRestAction.class).info("saving event " + event);
            eService.save(event);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(EventRestAction.class)
            .error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The "saving event" log is never printed. The server return with a 415 Unsupported media type error.

Just in case, here's the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ee.lapikud.ttyapp" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="ee.lapikud.ttyapp.interceptor.RequestSecurityInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>


</beans>
```

The question is quite broad, but I'm pretty stuck - what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Which version of spring are you using ? I have struggled on a similar issue, which was solved by downgrading to 3.0.5-RELEASE. Later versions have a few glitches...

Comment: Sorry, I've been off that project for over a year now, can't give anymore details on account of not remembering much of it. I'm pretty sure this was never solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely due to the `content-type` header of HTTP request/response. Can you make sure they are `application/json` both ways?

**Udpate**:
Spring config that finally worked for me (comments)

```
<bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
      <map>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
      </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="defaultViews">
      <list>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Yes, the content-type is `application/json`. The weirdest thing is, I post an object in another place in my app. For all intents and purposes, those two requests and the code is identical. The other one works fine.

Comment: Yeah, these are pretty hard to track down. I had this once and finally ended up attaching spring source code to the server jars and debugging. I remember my content-type being overridden because I had my ViewResolvers were not setup correctly for JacksonJsonView.